# What does "the fabric of space and time" actually mean?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question, spacetime, terminology

I've heard the term "the fabric of space and time" in both physics and science fiction, and although I know it has something to do with general relativity, I don't understand what, specifically, they're referring to.

Comment: It's not a technical term. It doesn't have a precise meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Einstein's theory space and time is single entity called spacetime. We treat spacetime as a smooth fabric which is distorted by presence of energy.Thus the term the fabric of space and time.The term fabric is used to help us visualize how spacetime works in GR.

Comment: Einstein: "...Recapitulating, we may say that according to the general theory of relativity space is endowed with physical qualities; in this sense, therefore, there exists an ether. According to the general theory of relativity space without ether is unthinkable; for in such space there not only would be no propagation of light, ... But this ether may not be thought of as endowed with the quality characteristic of ponderable media, as consisting of parts which may be tracked through time. The idea of motion may not be applied to it."

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a poetic or at least suggestive way to talk about the metric of space-time, about the fact that space-time can be curved, and its curvature changes from point to point, depending, as the other poster says, on the amount of mass-energy present at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions of fabric include "underlyimg structure" and "framework." I believe the usage is referring to those definitions.